# How do I make a menu appear after clicking an animated icon in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website and I have an icon that can animate (it goes from 3 bars to an x). However, I cannot seem to get a menu to appear below it after I click it.

I have tried:
Adding an if statement so that when the icon is clicked the menu appears.

adding a menu button then adding the links inside of the container.

but nothing seems to work.

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<head>
<title>JJ's Contracting Services.com</title>
<style>
 h1 {
     position: absolute;
     top:0;
     left:16px;
 }
 .header  {
     width:auto;
     padding: 200px;
     color: white;
     background-image: url(https://ak6.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1022525326/thumb/1.jpg);
     background-position: center top;
   }


 img {
     z-index: -1;
     vertical-align: text-top;
     top:0;
     width:100%;
     height:200px;   
 }

 .container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:absolute;
    right:30px;
    top:10;
 }

 .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;

 }

 .change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
 }

 .change .bar2 {opacity:0;}

 .change .bar3 {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
      transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
 }

     @media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
        .header  {
            width:100%;
         }
     }

 </style>
 <div class= "header">

 <h1>JJ's Contracting Services</h1>


 </div>
 <div class = "container" button onclick="myFunction(this)">   
     <div class = "bar1"> </div>                  
     <div class = "bar2"> </div>
     <div class = "bar3"> </div>  
 </div>  
 <script>
     function myFunction(x) {
        x.classList.toggle("change");             
     }    
 </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have the function `myFunction` twice?  That's a conceptual problem.

Comment: I didn't even notice that I fixed it but it doesn't do anything different. I'll send the code with just the code for the icon.

Comment: I figured out what went wrong my <div> tags were in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

As in your code, `change` class will make the menu. You can toggle change class in jquery easily in the following way.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.container').click(function(){
            $('#menu').toggleClass('change')
         }
    })
</script>
```

But to this work, you should create a div with the id `#menu` so that jquery and use it to toggle the class.

```
<div class= "header">
    <h1>JJ's Contracting Services</h1>
</div>
<div class = "container" button onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <div class = "bar1"> </div>                  
    <div class = "bar2"> </div>
    <div class = "bar3"> </div>  
</div>
<div id="menu"></div>
```

Don't use hamburger menu class(3 line button) to toggle as it converts the button into a menu. It will not look nice.